# Using Union results to filter a match using With

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I wish to use the results of a UNION (n) as a filter for a subsequent match.

```
MATCH (n:Thing)-<<Insert valid match filters here>> 
RETURN n
UNION
MATCH (n:Thing)-<<Insert a different set of match filters here>>
RETURN n;
```

n feeds into:

```
MATCH (n)-[:RELTYPE1]->(a:Artifact);
RETURN a;
```

I would expect to use a WITH statement, but I've struggled to figure out how structure the statement.

```
MATCH (n:Thing)-<<Insert valid match filters here>> 
RETURN n
UNION
MATCH (n:Thing)-<<Insert a different set of match filters here>>
WITH n
MATCH (n)-[:RELTYPE1]->(a:Artifact);
RETURN a;
```

This was my original attempt, but the WITH is interpreted as the start of subquery of the UNION's second match (which makes sense).

I can see a few inelegant ways to make this work, but what is the proper approach?

Comment: There is already a github issue on this, so using UNION and continue to filter / project will come at some point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  The [github issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725) is exactly what I'm looking for.  One thing to note: the post provides an example for how to do it today, which is basically to duplicate the terms of the match which goes against the aggregated result, to appear in each of the Union matches (so ax+bx rather than x(a+b). I prefer Dave B's approach as no duplication is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking at your union example and it makes sense to me but I cannot see how I could make it work. But I am certainly not the guy with all of the answers.  Is there a reason you couldn't do something like this though...

```
MATCH (n:Thing)
WHERE n.name = 'A'
WITH collect(n) as n1
MATCH (n:Thing)
WHERE n.name = 'B'
WITH n1 + collect(n) AS both
UNWIND both AS n
MATCH (n)-[:RELTYPE1]->(a:Artifact);
RETURN a;
```

Comment: This works very well! One addition I made was to place a 'with distinct' after the unwind to ensure uniqueness in the set.